# NullPointerException when I try to find files into HDFS, spark

Tags: apache-spark, error-handling, hdfs, hadoop2

I'm working in a cluster scenario.
The code works well if I consider one file into hdfs, but when I try to list all files into a directory, in order to process them one file per time, as follow

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
val files = new File("hdfs://nh-me:9000/user/user1/TotalFIle/").listFiles.map(_.getName).toList
```

I get the following error, notice that line 53 in which occur the error is the fourth line above in the piece of code that I posted:

```
17/02/14 23:57:19 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
at     scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef$.length$extension(ArrayOps.scala:192)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.length(ArrayOps.scala:192)
at scala.collection.SeqLike$class.size(SeqLike.scala:106)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.size(ArrayOps.scala:186)
at scala.collection.mutable.Builder$class.sizeHint(Builder.scala:69)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder.sizeHint(ArrayBuilder.scala:22)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.builder$1(TraversableLike.scala:230)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
at SparkGraphGen$.main(CorrDistGraph.scala:53)
at SparkGraphGen.main(CorrDistGraph.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:627)
17/02/14 23:57:19 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Java File APIs to access files on HDFS. Here is an example of using HDFS APIs to access files:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

val path = new Path("hdfs://nh-me:9000/user/user1/TotalFIle/")
val fs = path.getFileSystem(new Configuration())
val files = fs.listStatus(path).map(_.getPath.getName).toList
```